# Cannot upload iOS app with Facebook SDK 3.0 because references non-public selectors

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I can't upload my app linked to Facebook SDK 3.0.
It was rejected with this kind of false-positive (?) private API usage:

```
The app references non-public selectors in <appname> setAttribution:
```

I think it's related to facebook sdk framework:
I've found this reference inside framework's binary file https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbPTs.jpg

I've not used such method and FB.framework is the only thirdy party linked framework in my app.

Any idea?

**I've just tried to remove FacebookSDK.framework and all referenced code and it works fine...so I suppose it's a problem with setAttribution: call somewhere inside that code.**

Comment: If you've solved your problem, post your solution or accept one of the given answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've retry to upload it today and everything is fine now. Probability Apple has fixed something.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this issue today, but I found a good solution for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448056/the-app-references-non-public-selector-in-id-facebook-sdk-ios). See if it works for you too.