# Application Loader Warning: The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<Appname>.app/<App name>: id

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store-connect

Hi I got this warning when submitting my app to itunes store through Application Loader.

`The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<Appname>.app/<App name>: id`

How can i prevent the warning ?

NOTE : I am unsing latst facebook sdk. where i am using FBGraphUser id variable as `user.id`

Thanks,

Comment: this solved the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448056/the-app-references-non-public-selector-in-id-facebook-sdk-ios

Answer (score 1):

I think your code (or third party code) is using some private API, not a documented/public one.