# App with Google Analytics Got Rejected for Using UDID

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics

I just updated Google Analytics library in my app with newer version 2 (beta) but app got rejected by Apple stating:

Non-public API usage:
Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6.

I thought they would fix it by now as they did for GAD...
Is there a temporary fix for this or am I to wait until Google releases an update for Google Analytics library?

Comment: Are you using TestFlight as well? According to one of the posts here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463455/app-reject-google-analytics-ios-sdk-2-0 TestFlight uses UDIDs, but Google Analytics no longer does, per Google engineer Neil Rhodes

Comment: Only Google Analytics used. No TestFlight. One more libraries used is ShareThis. I have to verify it they may be using it.

Comment: Found. libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a has a reference to UDID.

Comment: How did you fix it then? Did you just delete this ref to UDID?

Comment: I removed this file as it is optional and built successfully. But when I resubmitted, Apple rejected again. Help!

Comment: OK I found Aviary to be a part of the problem too. Removed and app was submitted OK.