# Tools for detecting where UDID is used

Tags: ios, uniqueidentifier

I submitted an update for my app to itunesconnect to discover that one of my third party libraries is using UDID. It was not picked up when I first submitted the app and I have made no changes to my third party libraries since then. Is there a tool that I can use to discover which one is using it. I have looked manually through them, but found nothing...

Comment: `strings *.o | grep uniqueIdentifier`

Comment: strings...do I need to download that from anywhere?

Comment: @BoogTracki `strings` and `grep` are standard command line commands available on most Unix systems including OS X. Run `Terminal` and enter that command on the command line.

Comment: Ok. So, I put the file path for *.o. How do I connect it to that archive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing cmd+shift+f on the project and search for [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]

Comment: I did. I found nothing...but thanks. Any other suggestions?

Comment: which third party libraries are you using?

Comment: Kumulos, Facebook (the version before the current, so there shouldn't be any problems), and zbar

Comment: I use zbar in one of my app store apps so you can probably rule that out.

Comment: Kumulos has an article stating a safe version long before I began using it...so that's out.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid

Comment: That link is what I'm looking for, but the instructions how to implement for my app are vague. Do I just plug in: find . | grep -v .svn  | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier

Comment: You need to open Terminal and from the command line navigate to your project and run the grep commands listed

Comment: It was kumulos because I was using the wrong library...thanks