# Apps are not permitted to access the UDID

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store-connect, udid

I am facing this issue while submitting the app to the iTunes Connect as

[image]

I have tried this links, which were not helpful for me.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489079/apps-are-not-permitted-to-access-the-udid-and-must-not-use-the-uniqueidentifier)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569769/appstore-submission-denied-apps-are-not-permitted-to-use-the-udid)
[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid)

Kindly review your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: From 1st May update from apple [Deprecated UIDevice Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html) check into you project that you are use uniqueDeviceIdentifier then please put it's Alternate  identifierForVendor

Comment: Check whether you are using uniqueIdentifier method, also if you are using any third party library check whether that also not using these methods.

Comment: I had face this problem in past at that time  I was using old version of bug sense and that use UDID internally .So plz check any of your api or third party api doesn't use UDID internally.

Comment: @ user1548843: I was using older version of third party API. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDID is deprecated, and it's use is no longer allowed, you must use UUID.

It has drawbacks and benefits compared with UDID.

```
- (NSString *)uuidString {
// Returns a UUID

    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    NSString *uuidStr = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuid);


    return uuidStr;
}
```

- UDID always returned a unique and consistent ID. UUID whilst unique will return different every time. You need to store in user defaults or whereever and only generate if it's not already there.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I was doing mistake by using older version of third party API.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple guidelines you should use advertisingIdentifier.
Problem that in iOS 5 it's not working.
Feel free to use this code:

```
- (NSString *) advertisingIdentifier
{
    if (!NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")) {
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"uniqueIdentifier");
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            return [[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:selector];
        }
        //or get macaddress here http://iosdevelopertips.com/device/determine-mac-address.html
    }
    return [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I was doing mistake by using older version of third party API.