# iOS Non-Public API Causes Failed Validaiton

Tags: ios, api, udid

My app failed validation saying it used a non-public API.  The next line was talking about not being allowed to use UDID any more.

Does this mean I have two errors, or does this mean that the UDID IS the non-public API my app is using?

I am just not for certain if I am dealing with two seperate issues or if it is all one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

[[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier) is the method in question. You can no longer collect UDIDs from devices.

Check out this question to find which file is requesting the UDID:
[App rejected, but I don't use UDID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid)

If you are the one calling uniqueIdentifier, you need to use identifierForVendor in UIDevice or advertisingIdentifier in ASIdentifierManager. Most commonly, UDID issues are from external tracking code.

Comment: More correctly, you mean the `UIDevice uniqueIdentifier` method. There is no `UDID` API. It is not private. It is deprecated. More importantly, as of May 1, 2013, Apple no longer accepts apps that use it.

Comment: Correct. Edited the response for accuracy.