# "uniqueIdentifier" is banned by Apple to use

Tags: facebook, ios6

I want to upload my iPhone app but the problem is that Facebook ios SDK is using "uniqueIdentifier" because of this issue I am not to able to upload my app on app store.Any possible solution ?
Apple has banned uniqueIdentifier that why this issue is coming so please suggest me possible solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of :[App rejected, but I don't use UDID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `otool` command to identify precisely which libraries are at fault, with `grep` still providing a pool of suspicious files. As shown in my [blog post here](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/tutorial-finding-calls-to-uniqueidentifier-in-your-ios-app/), the following command will only output non-blank lines for libraries that actually cause an issue:

```
for match in $(grep -lR uniqueIdentifier *); do printf "File:%s\n\n" $match; otool -v -s __TEXT __objc_methname $match | grep uniqueIdentifier; printf "\n\n"; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance that facebook isn't the problem. run

```
$ find . | grep -v .svn  | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier
```

in the project folder. The out put was something to do with `Accounts`?
 I believe that your problem is the Accounts framework. If it's not used in your project just remove it.

Comment: When i execute this command this shows 

$ find . | grep -v .svn  | grep "\.a" | grep -v "\.app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier

Comment: When i execute this command 
grep -ir "uniqueIdentifier". 
then i got following result and result shows uniqueIdentifier matches
in binary file. Please suggest possible solution for this.
Binary file ./FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK matches
Binary file ./FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/.svn/text-base/FacebookSDK.svn-base matches
Binary file ./FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/FacebookSDK matches
Binary file ./FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/Current/.svn/text-base/FacebookSDK.svn-base matches
Binary file ./FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/Current/FacebookSDK matches

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but... ensure you have [the most recent and up-to-date version of the Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/) in your project, v3.5.1 as of April 24, 2013. If memory serves, however, I think they removed UDID from their SDK quite a while ago. Note that depending on how old your current version of the SDK is, you will have a varying amount of work to do to upgrade to the latest SDK.