# Why do I get an UDID error in Xcode 5? I submitted the same build on Xcode 4 three weeks ago with no issues

Tags: xcode, xcode5, udid

This is my first post here. I have an emoji app for iPhone that I recently had my developer update. The original app is from December last year. But with the new update my developer did, all SDKs were update (Appirator, Chartboost, Revmob + we added Appoxee and Tapjoy). So all SDKs were updated and the UDID issue that you would get with an old SDK should be handled.

And at first it seemed to be. I submitted my updated app about three weeks ago. The update went through Xcode (the latest version of Xcode prior to Xcode 5) and went into review 1-2 weeks after. Unfortunately I pulled a Homer and forgot to submit my IAPs on iTunes Connect. So naturally I was rejected. I went and set up my IAPs properly, and opened my emoji app in Xcode 5 (since I had updated to iOS 7 and Xcode 5 in the meantime). Now all of the sudden I first got a bunch of errors when building. They were library path errors, and luckily I could easily fix those by searching for ".a" in Xcode, clicking on each SDK, and then under "Target Membership" I could simply tick off and tick on the box - that fixed the library path problem.

After this I went to archive and then validate my app. But now I began getting the UDID error. Which I really don't understand considering all SDKs were updated and I didn't get the UDID error just a few weeks ago when I successfully submitted the app.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Would really appreciate it!

Here is a screenshot of the UDID error:
http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/5497/i1rx.png

Comment: You might find this useful in tracking down where the UDID is being used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid

Comment: More correctly, the problem is with calling the `UIDevice uniqueIdentifier` method. It is not allowed anymore. There are countless existing posts on how to fix and/or find the cause of this issue. Most likely you are using an older version of a 3rd party library that makes the call.

Answer (score 1):

So according to Apple Doc we should not UDID of device at any point of time.If you still want to use UDID or want unique id for device there is one library called Open UDID you can use that without any restriction.here is the link https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID check any of your class is directly using UDID of device.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really want UDID. What I don't understand is why Xcode says my app uses UDID when I believe it doesn't. I just want to submit my app, but I keep getting this error

Comment: check if your using any external library which is using UDID directly

Answer (score 0):

You can make a category on UIDevice with uniqueIdentifier method and add a breakpoint.

After That you should run your app and wait for breakpoint stop. Using backtrace you can find library that invokes uniqueIdentifier method.

[More about UDID on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/)