# Issues found during app upload to App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, ios7

It shows error when upload app to app store.

The error is

i) Your app contains non-public API Usage. Please review the errors, correct them and resubmit your application

ii) Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of uiDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the vendor or advertising identifier introduced in ios6.

iii) If u think this message was sent in error and that you have only used Apple-published APIs in accordance with the guidelines.

Can anyone know kindly help me?

Comment: This question has been asked many many many times before: duplicate of [App rejected, but I don't use UDID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid), [App rejected, but I don't use UDID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409966/app-rejected-but-i-dont-use-udid)

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Refrain from using `uniqueIdentifier` - it is not allowed now, blacklisted.