# getting The app references non-public selector in MyApp : id error while uploading the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am getting this error `The app references non-public selector in MyApp : id` while uploading the app to app store, I have searched a lot and found that such error are due to older api.

Is it so?

The API I am using are `ASIHTTPRequest`, `Facebook SDK`, `GAITracker for Google Analyst` in my application . Please provide me a solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448056/the-app-references-non-public-selector-in-id-facebook-sdk-ios

Comment: Thanks Rushabh for your reply , I had already looked that link. But that was not the problem. I resolved it. Actually the problem was due to GAItracker api. But it only generates warning , apple never rejects the app.