# Application Loader Warning: The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<Appname>.app/<App name>: changeState:

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this application loader warning and I have no idea where it is coming from. I have the facebook and parse sdk in my app. I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448056/the-app-references-non-public-selector-in-id-facebook-sdk-ios). It didn't help me, though, since my problem is apparently with something called changeState. That is not being called anywhere within code that I have written for my app. I also don't use the facebook sdk, I am required to have it in app with the parse sdk. How can I resolve this?

Comment: ⌘+⇧+⌥+F and search for `changeState:`

Comment: @CodaFi I did that and it found no results?

Comment: You can check the "statechange" in your directory by using this command 
grep -R "changeState" <Foldername with path>

You will get the directory in which it exists.

Answer (score 0):

changeState is used in libGoogleAdMobAd.a, part of Google AdMob.

I made a mention of it in the Review notes and my app was approved.