# Facebook 3.x prevents iOS App store validation

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

Recently (as in, since iOS 7 got released) when validating one of my apps in the Apple App store, validation failed with a very strange and -open to suggestion- reason;

`The app references non-public selectors in Payload/Name-of-apk/Name-of-app: setObject`

After disabling all kinds of pieces of code, it turns out that the app only passes validation when the Facebook SDK is removed from the project. It seems like the SDK is using a non public call which will reject the app from being submitted into the store.

I'm using the latest version of the Facebook SDK (3.8) for iPhone development. But have replicated the same problem in earlier versions (3.5 and 3.2).

Can anyone confirm that this actually is the case?

Comment: +1, I get the following warning with Facebook SDK 3.8: `The app references non-public selectors in Payload/Name-of-apk/Name-of-app: id`

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem with `setObject` method. I got the warning about `id` property. As for `id`, the workaround is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448056/the-app-references-non-public-selector-in-id-facebook-sdk-ios#14448057).