# app references non-public selectors in Payload/<appname.app/<Appname> id,setId

Tags: ios, facebook, validation, selector, application-loader

I submitted my iOS app today and got a validation warning:

app references non-public selectors in Payload/ id,setId

The code hasn't changed so I am guessing Apple's validation algorithm has changed.  I found one place in my code where I was using

```
user.id
```

for some Facebook functions, and changed that to use:

```
[user objectForKey:@"id"]
```

But I still get the validation warning with this change.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to find the offending "id" usage that is causing this validation warning?

I have no idea if Apple will reject the app, so I'll post back in about a week and update this post if they do.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order to clarify your question, could you link to the API that you are using?  What kind of object is `user`?

Comment: Please refer this link might be helpfule
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/42 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448056/the-app-references-non-public-selector-in-id-facebook-sdk-ios

Comment: Was your application accepted or rejected on the App Store finally ?

Comment: You were expected to post a reply :O